# Scala iterator on pattern match

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, apache-spark-sql

I need help to iterate this piece of code written in Spark-Scala with DataFrame. I'm new on Scala, so I apologize if my question may seem trivial.

The function is very simple: Given a dataframe, the function casts the column if there is a pattern matching, otherwise select all field.

```
/* Load sources */
val df = sqlContext.sql("select id_vehicle, id_size, id_country, id_time from " + working_database + carPark);


val df2 = df.select(
       df.columns.map {
         case id_vehicle @ "id_vehicle" => df(id_vehicle).cast("Int").as(id_vehicle)
         case other         => df(other)
       }: _*
    )
```

This function, with pattern matching, works perfectly!

Now I have a question: Is there any way to "iterate" this? In practice I need a function that given a `dataframe`, an `Array[String]` of *column* (column_1, column_2, ...) and another `Array[String]` of *type* (int, double, float, ...), return to me the same `dataframe` with the right cast at right position.

I need help :)

Comment: When you say your function takes in 2 arrays. Does the first column name go to the first type in the other array. So that they'd always have the same length?

Comment: Yes, the same length! Otherwise occurs an error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Your supplied code fits nicely into this function
def castOnce(df: DataFrame, colName: String, typeName: String): DataFrame = {
    val colsCasted = df.columns.map{
        case colName => df(colName).cast(typeName).as(colName)
        case other => df(other)
    }
    df.select(colsCasted:_ *)
}

def castMany(df: DataFrame, colNames: Array[String], typeNames: Array[String]): DataFrame = {

   assert(colNames.length == typeNames.length, "The lengths are different")
   val colsWithTypes: Array[(String, String)] = colNames.zip(typeNames)
   colsWithTypes.foldLeft(df)((cAndType, newDf) => castOnce(newDf, cAndType._1, cAndType._2))
}
```

When you have a function that you just need to apply many times to the same thing a fold is often what you want.
The above code zips the two arrays together to combine them into one.
It then iterates through this list applying your function each time to the dataframe and then applying the next pair to the resultant dataframe etc.

Based on your edit I filled in the function above. I don't have a compiler so I'm not 100% sure its correct. Having written it out I am also left questioning my original approach. Below is a better way I believe but I am leaving the previous one for reference.

```
def(df: DataFrame, colNames: Array[String], typeNames: Array[String]): DataFrame = {
    assert(colNames.length == typeNames.length, "The lengths are different")
    val nameToType: Map[String, String] = colNames.zip(typeNames).toMap
    val newCols= df.columns.map{dfCol =>
        nameToType.get(dfCol).map{newType => 
            df(dfCol).cast(newType).as(dfCol)
        }.getOrElse(df(dfCol))
    }
    df.select(newCols:_ *)
}
```

The above code creates a map of column name to the desired type.
Then foreach column in the dataframe it looks the type up in the Map. 
If the type exists we cast the column to that new type. If the column does not exist in the Map then we default to the column from the DataFrame directly.

We then select these columns from the DataFrame

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) But, for understand perfectly the concept, I need a little more bit of your help. My code now doesn't works: 

`def castOnce(df: DataFrame, colName: String, typeName: String): DataFrame = {
 df.select(
  df.columns.map {
   case x @ colName => df(x).cast(typeName).as(x) 
   case other => df(other)
  }:_*  
 )
}`

Now I can't iterate because the castOnce function is wrong: how do I iterate through the colName?

If I put a simple string like "somethig" in line `case x @ colName: String => df(x).cast(typeName).as(x)` the code works, but I have to iterate..

Comment: In your code, now, there are the same error for both functions that you posted: 


`error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column])
           df.select(newCols) // or df.select(colsCasted)`
I understand the concept, anyway I have to tell you: thank you! The second function is very compact, so it's better to use that!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. I think I fixed the compilation error for future reference for anyone else.

Comment: Yes!! Now it works perfectly! Thank you very very much!!! :-) Compliments!